# Algorithm to find three numbers in an array such that a< b < c and v[a]<v[c]<v[b]

Tags: algorithm, vector, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

Given a vector of integers, I need to find out if there exist three elements `a, b, c` in the vector such that `a < b< c` and `v[a] < v[c] < v[b]`.

My approach until now has been the following. First, I forget about a and find for every number in the vector the minimum of the v[i] that lie left of this element. I store this information in another array. Then I apply mergesort and when I reach the point where two elements cross, I test if the right element could be c and the left one b. However, I also need to test if the other elements that cross with the right element could be b, and this increases too much the time complexity. I need it to be linear at most.
Could yo give me a hint about how to proceed?

**EDIT:** Forgive me, the title wasn't OK before. What I need is that a < b < c and v[a] < v[c] < v[b]

**EDIT2:** ***Restriction***: I cannot use data structures, apart from vectors. And the algorithm has to be based on ***Divide and Conquer method***.

Comment: Such that a...? Please post your attempt to solve this.

Comment: If you're using C++, you can solve this by using `std::find_if` two times.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. Which would be the conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in *O*(*n*) time and worst-case *O*(*n*) extra space by iterating over the array while maintaining a stack (a LIFO data structure) of maximal forbidden ranges (`v[a]`, `v[c]`). The topmost element of the stack is the range from the least value seen so far to the greatest value seen since that least value. (Alternatively, for implementation reasons you may find it easier to keep that range in a separate variable, and only use the stack for *older* forbidden ranges.)

Processing any individual element can take up to *O*(*n*) time (if it has to unwind the entire stack all the way back to the very first range), but this cost is necessarily amortized, such that processing the entire array is still only *O*(*n*) time (because the only reason that processing an element would unwind the entire stack is if it's unifying all of the forbidden ranges into one much-larger one, in which case it doesn't need to re-add all of the ranges that it popped, so that work is only done *once*).

Comment: It looks right but I'm not familiar with those data structures right now. Isn't there a solution based on Divide and Conquer?

Comment: @Seven: Re: "I'm not familiar with those data structures right now": It's just one data structure; see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) for details.

Comment: I don't quite understand why  we can necessarily unify all the forbidden ranges

Comment: if we have the sequence 6,8,2,4,5 , when reaching 5 we will have to unwind the whole stack without unifying anything

Comment: @Seven: I didn't offer a precise definition of "unwind" in my answer, because I wanted to leave the details for you to figure out for yourself; but suffice it to say that in your example, you don't need to pop the range (6,8) off your stack, provided you have a way to examine the topmost element of a stack without having to remove it. (And even if you don't -- popping and re-adding one element is still O(1). Your overall algorithm remains O(*n*) as long as processing a given element never involves more than (say) two calls to `push`.)

Comment: @Seven: It may make more sense to you if you consider somewhat longer sequences, like [10,12,6,8,2,4,5] (where processing the 5 doesn't involve examining past the range (6,8)) or [10,12,6,8,2,4,9] (where processing the 9 unifies (6,8) and (2,4) into a single (2,9)). You never have to unwind the stack further than what you're unifying, except to examine *one* more element if you count that as "unwinding".

Comment: Forget about the word unwind. Don't you have to examine every range in the stack for every element over which you iterate ?

Comment: @Seven: No, not at all. Each range on the stack is strictly greater than all the ranges above it on the stack; so as you work your way down the stack, you can stop as soon as you reach a range whose upper bound is greater than or equal to the current array element, secure in the knowledge that any further ranges would be too high to be relevant.

Comment: But any element may be  smaller than this upper bound . Worst case performance is n^2, as I see

Comment: @Seven: Re: "any element may be smaller than this upper bound": I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. FWIW, I'm confident that this answer is correct, and gives O(n) worst-case performance. Keep trying, you'll get it. :-)

Comment: Thamk you . I think I now get what you are saying